# Envio de informações entre PC (Windows Form, C#) e Android

Tags: c#, winforms, bluetooth

Comecei a elaborar um esquema de projeto, e como ideia eu tinha de ter vários dispositivos Androids enviando dados para um computador (pretendo fazer usando Windows Form - C#, e talvez Xamarin pra parte Mobile).

Acabei ficando com dúvida na melhor forma de fazer o envio dos dados (Bluetooth, Wifi.. pois até então nunca fiz algo parecido).

Alguém poderia me ajudar com a forma que seria melhor (menor queda de conexões com o computador)?

Obs - Sei que existe uma api que trabalha com bluetooth (32feet), mas ainda sim fica minha dúvida qual seria melhor.

Agradeço a todos :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A melhor solução é você expor uma API (pode ser na sua aplicação Forms) aí você pode usar o [NancyFX](http://nancyfx.org/), ou criar um projeto API separadamente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nessa API você terá EndPoints e pela aplicação no Xamarin você poderá chamar esses endpoints para enviar/receber informações (GET/POST/PUT/DELETE).

Essa operação poderá ser via Wifi ou você poderá expor isso também na Web (deverá configurar DMZ ou NAT para o seu computador da rede local que está com a aplicação).

Links úteis:

**Xamarin Forms - Consumindo uma Web API ASP .NET com HttpClient**

http://www.macoratti.net/17/03/xamforms_webapi1.htm

**Consuming a RESTful Web Service**

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/cloud-services/consuming/rest/

No meu GitHub tem um exemplo de WebAPI que pode ser utilizada como base para o seu projeto também:

https://github.com/thiagoloureiro/WebAPIBase

Comment: Qual o motivo do downvote? Cade a pessoa que comentou e apagou? NancyFX Não é para ASPNET apenas.. MicroServiços em Console APP usam NancyFx por exemplo.

Comment: Exatamente o que eu precisava. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Maravilha Albert! Precisar de mais ajuda fico à disposição. 
https://medium.com/@thiagoloureiro/ escreva por lá que mantemos contato.

Answer (score 1):

Se quiser fazer algo amplo, que tenha acesso à vários computadores e poucos requisitos, recomendo usar Wi-Fi. Pois assim, você poderá trabalhar usando [soquetes de rede](http://www.macoratti.net/14/06/c_sock1.htm) e não é necessário usar alguma API de terceiros para enviar/receber estas informações.

O uso do Wi-Fi seria tanto para acesso externo quanto local, usando a rede local para emular todas as informações coletadas. Para fazer algo externo (que não usa rede local), seria necessário hospedar uma aplicação servidor em um endereço público para que os aplicativos celulares enviassem as informações para este servidor.

A perda de informação no Wi-Fi é causada quando a transmissão é interceptada por metais, longas distâncias, etc.

Usando Bluetooth fica mais complicado, teria que fazer chamadas Win32 e poucos computadores tem um sensor de Bluetooth. A não ser que você esteja fazendo isso para um grupo de computadores com específico Hardware cujo há o sensor será necessário fazer uma boa instalação, pois o que influencia na perda de dados Bluetooth é praticamente a mesma do Wifi.

Para mim, usando rede local Wi-Fi é a mais eficaz.